# Why can I not call the function StartTime outside of @IBAction func?

Tags: ios, swift, function, declaration

I am trying to start the timer before the user taps a button on the screen so when the app builds I expect the timer to start. When I try to call starTimer function outside of @IBAction func, under UIViewController Swift is thinking I am trying to declare a function. Why is this?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let eggTimes : [String : Int] = ["Soft": 5, "Medium": 7, "Hard": 12]
    startTimer(secondsRemaining: 60)

    @IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let hardness = sender.currentTitle!
        let result = eggTimes[hardness]!
        print(result)
        //startTimer(secondsRemaining: Int(readLine()!))
    }

    var secondsRemaining = 60

    func startTimer (secondsRemaining: Int){

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { (Timer) in
            if self.secondsRemaining > 0 {
                print ("\(self.secondsRemaining) seconds")
                self.secondsRemaining -= 1
            }else {
                Timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I try to call starTimer function outside of @IBAction func" Define "outside". Where exactly? You can't cell method from anywhere. There is a logic behind that.

Comment: That's what I thought. You can't call a method from there. You might want to call it in `viewDidAppear()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level of a `type` (class, struct, enum, etc.) is only for **define** functions and variables or anything else!

So you can **NOT** call anything there.

try to call your function inside a method that you know its going to be called like `viewDidLoad`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       startTimer(secondsRemaining: 60)
    }
...
```